# Is there a way I can access property of interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript. I want to access the isProd using  myStackObj. Like `myStackObj.isProd`.

```
interface MyStackProps {
    readonly isProd? : boolean;
}

class MyStack {
    constructor(props?: MyStackProps){
    }
}
let myStackObj = new MyStack({isProd: true});
myStackObj.isProd
```

myStackObj.isProd gives me error when I try to access this property. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make `props?` `public` and then do `myStackObj.props!.isProd`

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like you're actually assigning the value. The class should look like this:

```js
class MyStack {
    props: MyStackProps
    
    constructor(props?: MyStackProps){
      this.props = props;
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to access MyStack.props.isProd